# Add TR at the end of table dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I type in the input text (`.item-input`), it should add a new `tr` at the bottom of the `table` - it should copy from `class="template-row"` and change the class name to `class="row"` (Only new dynamically `tr` at the bottom)

It should also not keeping adding a new tr at the bottom if bottom input is empty (new `tr')

For some reason, it get added at the bottom of the table once and  `class="template-row"` tr get removed at the top which it shouldn't happen?

For example:

```
<style>
    .template-row { display: none; }
</style>

  <table>
       <tr class="template-row">
             <td> <input class='item-input' type="text"> </td>
       </tr>
      <tr class="row">
          <td> <input class='item-input' type="text"> </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item-input').on('keydown', function (e) {
        var itemName = $.trim($(this).val());

        if (itemName != '') {
            var templateRow = $(".template-row");

            $('table tr:last').after(templateRow).removeClass('template-row').addClass("row");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to clone the template not replace it.

Comment: @Mouser Ah, That kinda work but it didnt rename the class name from `template-row` to `row` for new dynamically `tr`. Feel free to post answer

Comment: Just `var templateRow = $(".template-row").clone();`

Comment: @dfsq Yep that work but class name does not get changed from template-row to row for new dynamically tr

Comment: Well I made a demo and it worked well for me. Not sure why it won't change class for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jquery:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item-input').on('keyup', function (e) {
      var itemName = $.trim($(this).val());

      if (itemName.length > 0 && $(this).data("copied") == undefined ) {
            var templateRow = $(".template-row").clone(true).removeClass('template-row').addClass("row");
            $('table').append(templateRow);
            $(this).data("copied", true);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
    .template-row { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table>
       <tr class="template-row">
             <td> <input class='item-input' type="text"> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="row">
             <td> <input class='item-input' type="text"> </td>
       </tr>    
  </table>
```

This code will add a new input every time the previous input get filled. It will execute only once per input.

- `$(this).data("copied")` Checks for a data-attribute `copied`. If present the input has been filled before and a new input was created. It sets an attribute to the `tr`-element called: `data-copied="true"`. `data` is really jQuery's shorthand for `attr("data-copied")`.
- `clone(true)` copies the template AND the events.
- After the cloning the template class is removed.

Comment: That work great, thanks.. How does `$(this).data("copied")` work? this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which clones the node and appends it to an element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item-input').on('keyup', function (e) {

        var itemName = $.trim($(this).val());

        if (itemName != '') {
            var templateRow = $(".template-row").clone();

            templateRow.appendTo('table').removeClass('template-row').addClass("row");
        }
    });
});
```